# How to remove this subquery from this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a SQL statement that does left join with a table:

```
select a.id, b.col1 from tableA a
left join (select col1 from tableB where date = 'xxx') b on a.id = b.id
```

For some application constraint (I need to use Spring JPQL query that does not permit subquery), I need to "flatten" this query to remove the subquery without changing the meaning of the query: I want to enrich tableA with a subset of tableB.

I have tried a few queries such as:

```
select a.id, b.col1 from tableA a
left join tableB b on a.id = b.id
where (date = 'xxx' or date is null)
```

But that gave me different set of answer from previous query.

How do I remove this subquery?

Comment: ```select a.id, b.col1 from tableA a left join tableB b on a.id = b.id and b.date = 'xxx'```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hi, you say "But that gave me different set of answer from previous query." but you use different conditions in where clause in first and in second query ? First query: "where date = 'xxx'" and second query: "where (date = 'xxx' or date is null)". Can you explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in multiple different ways - using cte, using joins

Using join it can be implemented as -

```
select a.id, b.col1 from tableA a left join tableB b on a.id = b.id and b.date = 'xxx'
```

using CTE it can be implemented as -

```
with t as 
(
select col1, id from tableB where date = 'xxx'
)
select a.id, b.col1 from tableA a
left join t on a.id = t.id
```